# Weird behaviour while checking nulls in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers with nulls in. I want to get the number of non-null element count. My code:

```
var arrayWithNulls = [null, 8, 3, null, 5, 0, 9];

var cleanArray = [];

for(i = 0; i < arrayWithNulls.length; i++){ 
    if(arrayWithNulls[i])
        cleanArray.push(arrayWithNulls[i]);
}

console.log(cleanArray.length);
```

But I get 4 instead of 5 as result. What am i missing?

Comment: `if(arrayWithNulls[i] !== null)`

Comment: So the problem is 0 both can mean a number and false in js, easy to miss

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy for more falsy values.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this behaviour because `0` is a falsy value.

You can change the code to the following if they include only numbers:

```js
var arrayWithNulls = [null, 8, 3, null, 5, 0, 9];

var cleanArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < arrayWithNulls.length; i++){ 
    if(typeof arrayWithNulls[i] === 'number')
        cleanArray.push(arrayWithNulls[i]);
}
document.write(cleanArray.length);
```

These are the falsy values in JS for your reference: 
    `false, null, undefined, '', 0, NaN`

Comment: Thank you, it is better to check if it is  number

Comment: note that will exclude objects and strings and other stuff too

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes that was the statement in the OP's question. It is an array of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For just counting, I suggest to use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a number variable for the result instead of an array and the misuse of length.

```js
var arrayWithNulls = [null, 8, 3, null, 5, 0, 9],
    nullCount = arrayWithNulls.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + +(a === null);
    }, 0);

document.write(nullCount);
```